# Simple way to print structured SQL SELECT in bash

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, echo, shapes

I'm trying to echo the output of a SELECT request in bash, in a structured form with column names. The issue is that i cannot do it properly with more than 2 fields or if the value is larger that the column name.

Example :

My table looks like this : value1 value2

If i do in bash : echo "select value1, value2 from table" | mysql -uUSER -pPASS

The result looks like this in bash :

```
value1  value2
a       d  
b       e
c       f
```

Now if i have 3 fields or a large value the result looks like this :

```
value1 value2 value3
aaaaaaaaa ddddddddddd ggg
bbbb      eeeeeeeee   hhhh
ccccccc   fffffffff   iiii
```

Is there a simple way to have a structured result ? I mean with column names correctly spaced? I know it is possible to do it with a sort to get the largest value and add the number of spaces needed but it seems to be too much for a simple problem like this.

Do you have an idea? Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the mysql -e option to execute your query, and -t to print table output to stdout:

> mysql -uUSER -t -e "select value1, value2, value3 from table" -pPASS

Your output will look something like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+
| value1    | value2      | value3 |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
| aaaaaaaaa | ddddddddddd | ggg    |
| bbbb      | eeeeeeeee   | hhhh   |
| ccccccc   | fffffffff   | iiii   |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

From the mysql manpage:

```
--execute=statement, -e statement

       Execute the statement and quit. The default output format is like that produced with --batch. See Section 4.2.3.1, “Using Options on
       the Command Line”, for some examples. With this option, mysql does not use the history file.
```

and

```
-table, -t

       Display output in table format. This is the default for interactive use, but can be used to produce table output in batch mode.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "select value1, value2 from table" | mysql -uUSER -pPASS | column -t
```

Comment: This worked for what I was looking for.  I wanted the column headings to be output with the data.  I then piped it to sed so I could turn the tabs into a CSV output.  Thanks - been looking for this for a while!

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is By Not Using Echo to just print Everything to Webpage, Instead you need to assign Each with an Array Variable.

will be something like this :

```
int x[50];

x[i] = $value // which is from SELECT Query
i++
```

and put it in a Loop, so the result every time will be Stored in a new Location for Array. once you have saved all your results in an array, it will be much easier for you to organize, you can use Table in HTML

```
<table />
```

and Organize it to make it efficient for you to easily put the array of the variable in a loop, so basically you will have 2 loops. 1st loop to assign array to database attributes, Second Loop will be for Printing inside the table of HTML.

Comment: The output is in a bash shell, not in html :)

Comment: Then you need to organize it in PHP by adding echo "|", "--". and " " to Create your Table, also u need to develop a function that will see in all array what is the biggest String, How many Char and Use the "-" for every char. will be some long work, about 50 Lines of PHP Code with like 3 Loops and 2 If conditions.

Comment: It is not PHP/MYSQL, the output is printed in a Linux Shell.